# Cannot get Google Maps JavaScript API Key

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am attempting to use Snazzy Maps to implement a custom Google Map iFrame into my website, however I cannot retrieve an API key from the Google Development Console. The tutorial that Google provided follows an outdated interface.

After enabling the API I have no options or indications of where the key may be, I have three tabs "Overview", "Usage" and "Quotas" but no actual key...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on http://console.developers.google.com/ and selected your project, you should see a sidebar on the left side of the user interface. Below the API's menu item (underneath the section: APIs & AUTH) there should be an item called Credentials.

You can obtain your API credentials over there (API Key). Hope this will help.

[image: img]